# Rails : How to use an object along with a text_area_tag of form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, object

```
<%= text_area_tag :body_html, "", :class =>"required mceEditor", :id=>"txaEditableContent" %>
```

This is my code. I want this text_area_tag to be assigned to an object(object is note in my case) just like we use "form_for object" so that the :body_html goes straight into params[:note] on submit. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You have got to set first an instance of Note in the controller corresponding action:

```
@note = Note.new
```

Then, in your view put this form:

```
<%= form_for @note do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body_html, :class => "required mceEditor", :id => "txaEditableContent" %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Now when you click the submit button you should get the right post request as you needed.

Comment: So there isn't anyway to use an object with form_tag. Am i right? My thing is working now as I used form_for.

Comment: form_tag is a generic form helper while form_for generates form with attributes specific to your object (such as url, method - post/put etc...). You could use form_tag but that would require you to define all these attributes by yourself, as well as inputs names that should be set to note[attribute_name]